# Android small screen does not show View at the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, view, multiscreen

I have a FrameLayout that holds a LinearLayout (which contains some views) and RelativeLayout (which appears at the bottom of the screen )

on a 2.3.3 HTC device (small screen), this RelativeLayout does not appear, although on emulator 2.3.3 it works fine, and also any other version it works fine

any suggestions or links (i know you will request the code, but i assure you that it will make no difference, it's as simple as described)

Comment: Have you followed guideline given on http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Scroll View to show the whole layout on the small devices as well.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if i have a ListView inside this LinearLayout, will it be OK !?